# Backbone.JS collection reset event does not appear to fire

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I have created a simple **[Todo application on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jiewmeng/grhz9/6/)** to learn Backbone.JS. I have a `TodosModuleView` that wraps a form and `TodosView` which renders the Collection of Todos

```
window.TodosModuleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'section',
    id: 'todoModule',
    events: {
        'keypress #frmTodo input[type=text]': 'addTodo'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 
                        'addTodo');
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        this.template = _.template($('#todosModuleTmpl').html());        },
    render: function() {
        console.log('rendering...');
        var todosView = new TodosView({ collection: this.collection });
        this.$el.html(this.template({}));
        this.$el.append(todosView.render().el);
        return this;
    },
    addTodo: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode !== 13) 
            return;
        var todo = new Todo({ title: this.$('input[name=todo]').val() });
        this.collection.add(todo);
        console.log('added!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

When I add a todo, I can see it added to the collection, but it does not appear to trigger `render()`. Also since I am using a Local Storage store, I'd expect that my newly added Todos should be persisted and rendered on next refresh, but that does not appear to happen. Looking at the Chrome's developer toolbar, I don't see anything in Local Storage

**UPDATE**

1st Problem solved with **@mashingan's** answer: use `add` instead of `reset` event. Now whats wrong with my Local Storage?

```
window.Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('todos')
});
```

Could it be that variables are passed by value instead of reference as I'd expect? I have a `TodosModuleView` that uses `TodosView` to render the todo list, maybe I am doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LocalStorage isn't working because you're not saving anything. This:

```
var todo = new Todo({ title: this.$('input[name=todo]').val() });
this.collection.add(todo);
```

simply creates a new model and adds it to the collection, there is no hidden `todo.save()` call in there so the new `Todo` doesn't get saved. You'd have to save it yourself:

```
var todo = new Todo({ ... });
todo.save();
this.collection.add(todo);
```

You could also save everything in the collection with:

```
this.collection.invoke('save');
```

That will call `save` on each model in the collection. This might make sense for LocalStorage but not so much sense if you're persisting to a remote server.

If you do this:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('pancakes')
});
var c = new C;
c.add([
    { title: 'Fargo' },
    { title: 'Time Bandits' }
]);
```

Then you won't get anything in your `pancakes` database, but if you add `c.invoke('save')` at the end:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({});
#...
c.add([ ... ]);
c.invoke('save');
```

You will get a couple of good movies saved.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZV86g/

Comment: Yeah. You can also use [`collection.create`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) method.

Answer (score 1):

Check [backbone catalog of events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events): `reset` (collection) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced. There is `add` event which should work in your case.

Comment: That solves the 1st problem. For the 2nd, am I using the Local Storage adapter wrongly? When I refresh the page, all todos are gone, in Chrome Dev Tools, my Local Storage seems to be empty